# SSAS - dsv displays datetime instead of date

Tags: ssas

I added named query to my data source view, converting datetime to date. When I run the query it displays datetime anyway. Do you know how to fix this? I need date format to match with the  Time dimension.[image]

I'm using SQL Server Data Tools 2012.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL DATE datatype accepts time values, so that is how it is shown in the Query preview.  If the datatype of your Time dimension key is also DATE, then you should be OK to continue.  Have you tried?

FWIW I would use a BIGINT key for a Date Dimension, containing a date represented as YYYYMMDD.  This allows for extra rows e.g. with a -1 Key for unspecified dates (e.g. null in Fact data).

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for your answer. When I generate a time table on the server datetime doesn't match with date. When I use existing time table (from database) it matches, but in cube dates are being displayed as 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000. I don't want to show dates with time.

Comment: This is a completely unrelated issue.  I would add an attribute to the Time dimension to present the formatted date as a text value.